# Sublime Text 2 build with Grunt v0.4.0

Tags: build, sublimetext2, gruntjs

I'm trying to setup Sublime build process to run Grunt (v0.4)
This is my build snippet:

```
{
    "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"],
    "selector": ["Gruntfile.js"],
    "path": "/usr/local/bin",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "osx": {
        "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"]
    }
}
```

When I hit <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> I get the following error:

> grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.6)
>   Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
>   hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
>   installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
>
> http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
>   [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 99]

When I run `grunt` from the terminal everything is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a "bug" of Sublime Text. When you hit `Ctrl+B`, it will call the build command with the first open folder as the working directory. So if you haven't opened the folder, it cannot find the build file (Makefile, or in your case Gruntfile).

So in order to build successfully, you need to put your Gruntfile in the folder as the working directory, and then open the folder in Sublime Text and hit `Ctrl+B`.

Comment: Thanks,I had three folder in my project which in the last I had my Gruntfile.js When I closed the other folders and left only my folder with Gruntfile open, it did worked. Maybe there's a workaround to make it work with other folders?

Comment: Yes. Just place the Gruntfile folder on the first place. You can change the order of folders by drag and drop.

Comment: This selector does not seem to work if I set to "automatic" the build system. I would like to launch the grunt command only on the Gruntfile.js.

Comment: Maxime P: Perhaps "Gruntfile.js" isn't a valid selector because it doesn't contain the string "source" in it. Documentation on that is sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Before running GruntJS, you need to install it with:
npm install grunt --save-dev
In the new version of GruntJS, 'grunt' is not installed globally, so in every project you can use different versions of GruntJS.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that, as I mentioned when runinng "grunt" from the terminal it's working

Answer (score 0):

Enter `which grunt` from the command line, then put the full path in the `"cmd"` section - for example, `"cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/grunt", "--no-color"]`. The `$PATH` for ST2 can be different from the one in your CLI environment.